# AngularJs Module Run Block, Configuration, and Route Definition

Tags: javascript, angular.js, url-routing, cordova

My AngularJs app is currently working fine. I'm working on modularity, refining my code design, and making it more readable. I have a `app.js` file that contains the module, the run block, and configuration definitions. By default Ionic uses the Ui-Router for route definition, so the routes are defined in my config block. I have several events attached to `$rootScope` defined in the `.run` block. I'm wondering if something can be abstracted a better way, or into a service. I'm look to refine the code as much as possible. The code is below:

```
(function () {

    'use strict'


    /*global angular */

    /**
     * The main app module
     *
     * @type {angular.Module}
     */

    angular
        .module('app', ['ionic',
            'ngCordova',
            'ngMessages',
            'app.events',
            'app.attendees',
            'app.filters',
            'app.login',
        'blocks.exception',
        ])

        .run(runBlock)

        .config(configure);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    runBlock.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$http', '$localstorage', '$ionicLoading', 'Podio'];
    function runBlock($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$state,$stateParams, $http,$localstorage,$ionicLoading,Podio) {

        $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function () {
            $ionicLoading.show();
        });

        $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,toState) {

            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');

            if(!toState.hasOwnProperty('requireAuthentication') || toState.requireAuthentication !== false){
                Podio.isAuthenticated()
                    .catch(function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $state.go('login');
                    });
            }

        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
        });

        /*
         * Local Storage Object Used*/
        $localstorage.get('password', function (token) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'OAuth2 ' + token.accessToken;
        });



        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)

            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleLightContent();

            }
        });

    }

    configure.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


        // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
        // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
        // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
        // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
        $stateProvider
            // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
            .state('tab', {
                url: '/tab',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'views/tabs.html'
            })

            // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

            .state('tab.events', {
                url: '/events',
                views: {
                    'tab-event': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/events.html',
                        controller: 'EventsController as eventsvm',
                        resolve: {
                            events: eventsPrep
                        }
                    }
                },
                params: {refresh:false}
            })
            .state('tab.event-detail',{
                url:'/event/:eventId',
                views: {
                    'tab-event':{
                        templateUrl: 'views/event.html',
                        controller: 'EventController',
                        resolve: {
                            event : eventPrep
                        }
                    }
                },
                params: {eventId: null,refresh: false} //must declare params here,
            })
            .state('tab.attendees',{
                url: '/attendees/:attendeeIds',
                views: {
                    'tab-event':{
                        templateUrl: 'views/attendees.html',
                        controller: 'AttendeesController',
                        resolve: {
                            attendees : attendeesPrep
                        }
                    }
                },
                params: {
                    eventId: null,
                    attendeeIds: {array:true},
                    refresh: false
                }
            })
            .state('tab.attendee-detail',{
                url: '/attendee/:attendeeId',
                views: {
                    'tab-event':{
                        templateUrl: 'views/attendee.html',
                        controller: 'AttendeeController',
                        resolve: {
                            attendee : attendeePrep
                        }
                    }
                },
                params:{
                    eventId: null,
                    attendeeId: null,
                    attending: true,
                    refresh:false
                }
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                requireAuthentication: false,
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/events');

    }


    eventsPrep.$inject = ['EventService', '$stateParams'];
    function eventsPrep (EventService,$stateParams) {
        return EventService.getEvents($stateParams.refresh);
    }

    eventPrep.$inject = ['EventService','$stateParams'];
    function eventPrep (EventService,$stateParams) {
        var eventId = $stateParams.eventId,
            refresh = $stateParams.refresh;
        return EventService.getEvent(eventId,refresh);
    }

    attendeesPrep.$inject = ['AttendeeService','$stateParams'];
    function attendeesPrep(AttendeeService,$stateParams) {
        var attendeeIds = $stateParams.attendeeIds;
        if(attendeeIds) {
            attendeeIds = JSON.parse(attendeeIds);
            var eventId = $stateParams.eventId,
                refresh = $stateParams.refresh;
            return AttendeeService.getAttendees(attendeeIds, eventId,refresh);
        }else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    attendeePrep.$inject = ['AttendeeService', '$stateParams'];
    function attendeePrep(AttendeeService,$stateParams) {
        var attendeeId = $stateParams.attendeeId,
            refresh = $stateParams.refresh;
        return AttendeeService.getAttendee(attendeeId,refresh);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hey, I was using this styleguide for my Angular project. I think it has really good ideas on how to structure your code/project

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using root scope and try using more [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) based architecture which is available in latest angular versions.Rather than using broadcast to communicate use service. separate each functionality into its own file and use build system like gulp to join it for you. So you could do

```
// root module.js
angular.module('app', ['ionic',
            'ngCordova',
            'ngMessages',
            'app.events',
            'app.attendees',
            'app.filters',
            'app.login',
        'blocks.exception',
        ])


// run block.js    
angular.module('app')
  .run(runBlock)
```

If possible use JavaScript ES6 with babel